# Android: Failing to update row using SQL Extension function or builtin

Tags: android, sqlite, spatialite

I'm having a lot of trouble with SQLiteDatabase command.  I have loaded up spatialite and enabled the extension.  I want one of my values to be the output of the MakePoint function so I have a content value like this:

```
values.put("Location", "MakePoint(43.2, 27.345, 4326)");
```

When this is passed into `SQLiteDatabase.Update()` it's escapsed so that the resulting string ends up being `"UPDATE Targets SET Location='MakePoint(43.2, 27.345, 4326)'"` SQLite hates this and throws an exception.

Is there an easy way around this? Right now I'm trying to build up the string manually since I can't use Update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  I have to do a "SELECT MakePoint(43.2, 27.345, 4326)" first and then insert that into Location.

Answer (score 1):

`SQLiteDatabase` was not designed for the SpatiaLite extension.
`update()` supports only simple values, not generic expressions; you cannot use it to insert geographic objects.

The only way to execute your command is to build it manually an run it through `execSQL()`.

You could write your own database wrapper object that understands SpatiaLite data types.